# excel cell coloring

Tags: c#, colors, cell

I am using c# to color particular cells of excel file.
I am using:

```
Application excel = new Application();
Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(destPath);
 Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[1];
 ws.get_Range(ws.Cells[row, clmn]).Cells.Interior.Color = 36;
```

...to color cells, but this is not working.
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: It is giving exception "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try something like that

```
ws.Cells[row, clmn].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red)
```

Comment: It is giving exception "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"

Comment: How can I iterate through a column and check every row?

Comment: One thing that can cause the dreaded  "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC" is if the sheet is protected. Check `nWS.ProtectContents` before you try to change anything on the sheet.

Answer (score 9):

Cells[row, clmn] is a range so you don't need to call get_Range() and there is a enum that you can use for colors.

```
ws.Cells[row, clmn].Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbBlack;
```

Comment: `.Interior` isn't found`

Answer (score 7):

If you want to set color by color index, you need to use this method:

```
    Cells[row, col].Interior.ColorIndex = 36;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can color a cell or a entire column or entire row.

The below code will help you out.

```
xlWorkSheet.get_Range(xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 2], xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 4]).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Green);
```

else

```
xlWorkSheet.get_Range(xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 3], xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 3]).Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbRed;
```

Here **xlWorksheet** is the object excel Worksheet object.

**get_Range** takes 2 variable one start cell and other is end cell.

so if you specify both the values same then only one cell is colored.

**xlWorkSheet.cells[row, column]** is used to specify a cell.

**System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(SystemDrawing.Color.Green)** is used to define the color in OLE format.

**Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbRed** is a excel way of coloring the cells
This method gives access to large number of colors which can be found here [list of colors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlrgbcolor.aspx)

The below code is the way i defined the excel worksheet.

```
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
Excel.Range xlwidthadjust; //used this to adjust width of columns
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
```

with this code i am sure that you wont get this exception **Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC**

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

If you have a variable for the range you want to change, then use:

```
chartRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("a5", "a8");    
chartRange.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
```

If you want to just change the color of a specific cell, then use:

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells[row, col].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
```

...where 'row' is the row number, and 'col' is the column number assigned to the given lettered columns (starting at 1).

Answer (score -1):

`Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC`

Solution: Change the `misValue` to `sheet1`, `sheet2` or `sheet3`.

```
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add("sheet1");
```

This works for me. `system.reflaction.missing.value` what was that, it is not related to `Excel.workbooks.add` came from a Excel file default value.
When you create a Excel file, the default worksheets are sheet1, sheet2 and sheet3.