# Column coloring in excel via c#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I want to coloring a specific column of excel file with c#. But i can not find any example or useful information about it. I need help about this issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897062/excel-cell-coloring

Comment: what i actually mean is coloring a whole column

Comment: There are a *lot* of examples. How are you manipulating the Excel sheet? Do you use Interop, a VSTO addin or are you generating it with the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

An Excel range can be identified either by the row-column or an address string, eg: `A1` or `A:A` to select the first column.

The `Cells` property returns a range which means you can use both ways of addressing to select specific cells or an entire column, eg: `.Cells["A:A"]`.

To provide a specific code example though, we need to know *how* you are manipulating the Excel file. You may be using the Office Interop assemblies, running a VSTO addin inside Excel itself, or creating it with the Open XML SDK or a library like EPPlus

**EDIT**

When using Office Interop you can use the `.Columns` property of a Range or Worksheet object to select an entire column, eg:

```
myWorkSheeet.Columns[1,Type.Missing]
```

or

```
myWorkSheeet.Columns["A:A",Type.Missing]
```

`Columns` and `Cells` are both ranges so you can use the `"A:A"` address format in both cases

Comment: i use office interop assemblies. im trying to color a column according to data audit criteria result.