# Coloring of excel not working

Tags: c#, excel

from: [excel cell coloring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897062/excel-cell-coloring)

I have this:

```
Excel.Worksheet myExcelWorkSheet;
myExcelWorkSheet.Cells[rowNumber, "B"].Interior.Color = (...)
```

And it is not recognizing the Interior part..

> Error  2   'object' does not contain a definition for 'Interior' and no extension method 'Interior' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   D:\W\ProgGas\ProgGas\ExcelFile.cs   68  64  ProgGas

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
myExcelWorkSheet.GetRange(rowNumber,"B").Interor.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.YourColor);
```

Comment: no :/ `Error 1 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet' does not contain a definition for 'GetRange' and no extension method 'GetRange' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) D:\W\ProgGas\ProgGas\ExcelFile.cs 68 42 ProgGas
`